# How to reset a static variable in a Page in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm using a `static bool hasBeenLoaded = false;` in a Page, And there are times when I clear the navigation stack and then load this page, but still the hasBeenLoaded element will retain its older value.

Shouldn't this be cleared since I'm removing the entire BackStack before navigating?

Comment: Just don't make it static.

Comment: Static variables are...static, they don't belong to any instance, so they will not be uninitialized until the program finishes. I fyou want it to be destroyed wtih the class instance then just don't make it static.

Comment: Ok thanks I thought they would be available until the page is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear the value (neither true nor false) then declare the variable as nullable. ex. `static bool? hasBeenLoaded = value`. In case of reset, just
set `ClassName.hasBeenLoaded = null;`